# Static web page on github codespaces

Tags: github, web, port, liveserver, codespaces

I'm trying to use codespace and I want to build a web page that is as simple as possible, without using Nodejs, Django or any other framework. In VS Code I used live server and that's it, but in codespace I see that the extension is not available for vs code web. Also, maybe it was an error but in one of the tests I did it was seen that a bug occurred and it let me download it and use it perfectly, in any case, how can I download it is it enabled or not.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD61N.png)

I tried to configure a manual port but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to provide more information if you want us to be able to help.  Can you link to the website for the extension?  Why do you need this extension anyway?  Can't you just transfer your files to your host with FTP or SCP?